# How to serialize and deserialize an enum which is in an interface via GSON?

Tags: java, gson

I am trying to serialize and deserialize an enum which is inside an interface via GSON.
please help if someone has something on it. 
Thanks in advance.. :)

Here is my interface ..

```
public interface Module {
    @Expose
    public enum CATEGORY {
        INPUT,
        OUTPUT,
        LIGHTS,        
        COMMUNICATION,
        ...
    }
    @Expose
    public enum TYPE {
        INPUT,
        OUTPUT,
        ANALOG,
        DIGITAL,
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code at the below.

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Module.CATEGORY comm = Module.CATEGORY.LIGHTS;
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = gson.toJson(comm);
        if (gson.fromJson(json, Module.CATEGORY.class) == Module.CATEGORY.LIGHTS)
            System.out.println("It works!");

    }
}
```

prints:

> It works!

Serialize your enum via.

```
public interface Module {

    public enum CATEGORY implements Serializable {
        INPUT,
        OUTPUT,
        LIGHTS,        
        COMMUNICATION
    }
    public enum TYPE implements Serializable {
        INPUT,
        OUTPUT,
        ANALOG,
        DIGITAL
    }
}
```

Comment: one addition for this, i want to use it with Expose annotation in here.
Some what like this when we add Expose annotation but it gives error
for example :-
@Expose
public enum CATEGORY {
        INPUT,
        OUTPUT,
        LIGHTS,        
        COMMUNICATION
    }

Comment: You should update your question and see the answer for @Expose -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/7430002/668572

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Module.CATEGORY m = Module.CATEGORY.COMMUNICATION;
Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(m));
```

this will print the name of your enumerator,

Comment: one addition for this, i want to use it with Expose notation in here.

for example :-
@Expose
public enum CATEGORY {
        INPUT,
        OUTPUT,
        LIGHTS,        
        COMMUNICATION
    }

Comment: Some what like this when we add Expose annotation but it gives error.